# Почему - сидор?

Tags: этимология

Почитала тут про сидорову козу, и у меня возник другой вопрос о сидоре. А именно - о сумке.
Практический справочник русского языка З. Е. Александрова дает такое определение: "Сидор - вещмешок, сумка, рюкзак, заплечный мешок, исидор, портфель, мешок". Также это слово употреблялось для обозначение солдатского мешка по время войны.
И вот вопрос: почему он так называется? Это связано с мужским именем Сидор или просто созвучно ему?

Comment: По поводу сидровой козы. А что если здесь просто созвучие "Сидор - драть", такая своеобразная звукопись.

Answer (score 1):

Вещевой мешок уже в Русской императорской армии (РИА) назывался «сидор».

Одна из версий происхождения названия.http://eponim2008.livejournal.com/82890.html

Русское простонародное имя Сидор происходит от греческого имени, означающего "Дар Изиды". 
Небесный же покровитель всех русских Сидоров - христианский святой, мученик Исидор Хиосский, который в православии  называется "угодником Сидором" . Трудно сказать по какой причине, но имя это для русского слуха звучит не слишком уютно. Вспомним хотя бы пресловутую "сидорову козу", которую хозяин должен нещадно драть. Почему? Да потому что Сидор! Может, столь прохладное отношение к Сидору-Иссидору связано с тем, что в старину в день святого мученника Сидора, 14 мая по старому стилю, можно было ожидать последних заморозков.Так или иначе, слово "сидор" в применении к солдатским, а хуже того, арестантским заплечным мешкам особых протестов не вызвало и прижилось. Сидор - он и есть сидор.

"Сидором" называли и называют  полотняный или брезентовый мешок с двумя плечевыми ремнями и с горловиной, которая завязывалась веревкой или шнурком. В этот мешок складывались личные вещи солдата или заключенного. И тому, и другому полагался строго обозначенный набор предметов. За отсутствие таковых наказывали, так же как наказывали и за присутствие  предметов неразрешенных. В общем, как приговаривал старшина или надзиратель: "Должон быть порядок! Порядок быть должон!"

Многие словечки русского тюремного языка - ивритские корни. "Сидор" из той же семейки. Так на русский манер изменилось ивритское слово "седер" - "порядок". Который быть должон.

Answer (score 0):

Сумка Индивидуальная ДОРожная, все просто.